# Permalink like example.com/taxonomy/post_type/postname

Tags: php, permalinks, taxonomy, archives, post-type

I would like permalink structures like this:

`example.com/%post_tag%/post_type/postname` for posts

`example.com/%post_tag%/post_type`  for archive page of post_tag filtered with custom post type archive

`example.com/%post_tag%/`   for all posts of post_tag

Comment: Post may have several tags, how will you choose which one should be in the address (added as first, random, ...)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permalink structure like facebook.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332241/permalink-structure-like-facebook-com)